# how to implement coroutine pool in coroutine-support language?

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, coroutine

I'm wondering if it is approriate to implement coroutine pool in kotlin since coroutine itself is more lightweight than thread.

There's such a scene, code was wittern in Java:
I designed different kind of messages which are received from clients. These messages will be extracted a `msgId` and encapsulated into a task(which actually a `Runnable` in Java), and finally be dispathced to different `consumption queues` according to `msgId`.

The `consumption queues` actually are thread pool. These tasks will finally be processed by the processor related to the pool.

```
/*    
    The whole process is simplified into the following process method
*/
class MsgProcess {
    public void process(Msg msg) {
        int msgId = msg.getId();
        Task task = new AbstractTask(msg);
        Processor processor = ProcessorMap.getProcessorById(msgId);
        QueueDriver driver = processor.getDriver();
        driver.addTask(task);
    }
}

abstract class Processor {
    ...

    protected abstract QueueDriver getDriver(); // QueueDriver is the consumption queue
}

abstract class AbstractTask implements Runnable {
    ...

    @Override
    public void run() {
        ...
    }
}


class Task1 extends AbstractTask{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // remote procedure call to the script server to process the task
    }
}
```

Then an idea came into my mind, if in languages like Go and Kotlin that support coroutine, What can thread pools be replaced?  To design a coutine pool? Coroutine has already been lightweight. Is pooling design really meaningful

Or how to involve consumption queues for different tasks using coroutine?

Comment: There is no reason to bother with pooling coroutines.

Comment: Furthermore, be advised that with the release of Java 19 on the 20th of September 2022 java now supports "virtual threads", which are essentially fibers, (see "project loom") and languages like Go and Kotlin became obsolete overnight.

Comment: @MikeNakis virtual threads and coroutines solve different problems, and coroutines are not the only difference between Java and Kotlin.

Comment: @Tenfour04 would you like to discuss this? (Perhaps in one of the stack overflow chatrooms, or via some other means, like google hangouts, microsoft teams, etc.)

Comment: @MikeNakis [My answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053797/java-virtual-threads-vs-kotlin-coroutines/77059883#77059883) is the point I'm getting at about them solving different problems, but I'm not an expert at the details. But I don't think of coroutines as the main point of Kotlin. Even if Kotlin didn't have coroutines at all, I would usually choose it over Java because in most cases (for me) the pros outweigh the cons. If you want to open an SO chat room I can join, but I would be sporadic through the day.

Comment: @Tenfour04 yes, I saw your answer. Here is a chat room: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255344/virtual-threads-vs-coroutines I will also be sporadically available, that's okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Kotlin documentation talks about coroutines being lightweight threads, it’s just because coroutines use thread pools under the hood. Therefore, pooling coroutines would not provide any benefits, while it would defeat the other primary purpose of coroutines, simpler concurrency-related code.